# Storing user app data with an app with Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, storage

I would like to know how I would go about doing this so I know what I have to learn.

Context:
+ I want to create an App with a Facebook login.
+ My app stores data with a Player object.

Is there a way to tie the Player object data with the Facebook Login? Would this be using the Facebook "parameter" as a key to a SQL database for example? or does Facebook allow you to store each user's Player object data with Facebook?

Thanks for sharing!